# Section reference shows section then subsection number

Tags: cross-referencing

I am labeling a subsection with simply `\label{labelname}`, and referring to it later in my document with `\ref{labelname}`. However, at that point it doesn't print just the subsection number, e.g. `2.1`, but it prints the section number followed by the subsection number, like `2 2.1`. Can it be made to show the desired output?

Minimum example (using revtex4 class):

```
\documentclass[pre,12pt]{revtex4}
\renewcommand \thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand \thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand \thesubsubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\label{subsection1}
Some text.

\section{Section 2}
Previously seen in \ref{subsection1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably you have some redefinition on your preamble. Post your minimal code here.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that I'm using the revtex4 class.

Comment: Here it prints `IA` without dot. Try to delete `aux` files and `log` files.

Comment: By default, the representation for the `subsection` counter in cross-references will be `\thesection\, \Alph{subsection}`. Do you want something different?

Comment: There's a good reason for showing both the section as well as the subsection number when generating a cross-reference. Suppose you have subsections "numbered", say, `A` in sections II, III, and IV of your document. You'd be risking confusing your readers greatly if you just create a cross-reference to "subsection A" somewhere in the paper: is it supposed to be subsection `A` in section II, III, or IV? With enough time and energy, some readers will manage to figure out *which* of the three subsections is meant. All other readers will greatly appreciate call-outs of the form `II.A` or `IV.A`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file `revtex4.cls` contains the lines

```
\def\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}
\def\p@subsection{\thesection\,}
```

so the representation for a cross-references to a subsection will be typeset as the upper-case alphabetic representation for the `subsection` counter prepended by the counter for sections and a thin space:

```
\documentclass[pre,12pt]{revtex4}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\label{subsection1}
Some text.
\section{Section 2}
Previously seen in~\ref{subsection1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you have redefined `\thesubsection` to explicitly include the `section` counter, you'll get this counter duplicated. To prevent this, you can redefine `\p@subsection`; for example to suppress the prefix and keep just the representation for the `subsection` counter you could say:

```
\makeatletter
\def\p@subsection{}
\makeatother
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[pre,12pt]{revtex4}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}

\makeatletter
\def\p@subsection{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\label{subsection1}
Some text.

\section{Section 2}
Previously seen in \ref{subsection1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A similar redefinition of `\p@subsubsection` will have to be done, since the class does

```
\def\p@subsubsection{\thesection\,\thesubsection\,}
```

Comment: Strange! Reading the question I understand that he/she said that the reference number is 22.1 (*like 2 2.1*).

Comment: Hi, my minimum example stripped out code that I use to remove this ambiguity, i.e. by setting it to basically the default article class numbering (see updated preamble).

Comment: @dplanet same idea: redefine `\p@subsection`; see my updated answer.

Comment: @Sigur yes, in fact that was what he/she was getting due to the redefinition of `\thesubsection` as can be seen from the edit to the question; my initial suggestion  (redefining `p@subsection`) still applies.